# String Comparisons using LINQ Expressions and String.Format

Tags: .net, string, linq, string-comparison, linq-expressions

I'm using LINQ expressions to dynamically search for values in a collection and I've come across a strange issue that seems to be caused by searching for a string that is the result of a `String.Format()` operation.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do, since in practice I do not actually know what type of value I am searching for, I have to treat everything as an `Object`.

```
Dim stringToFind As String = "Some Special Value"

' Create a collection of 10 strings, one of which being the string to find '
Dim myStrings As New List(Of Object)
For i As Integer = 0 To 9
    If (i = 3) Then
        myStrings.Add(String.Format(stringToFind))
    Else
        myStrings.Add("Boring Plain Old Value")
    End If
Next

' Create the predicate for <Function(x) x = stringToFind> '
Dim left = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Object), "x")
Dim right = Expression.Constant(stringToFind)
Dim eq = Expression.Equal(left, right)
Dim predicate = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of Object, Boolean))(eq, left).Compile()

' Compare the results '
Dim standardResults = myStrings.Where(Function(x) x = stringToFind)
Dim expressionResults = myStrings.Where(predicate)

' Expected Output:'
' Standard Method: 1 '
' LINQ Expressions: 1 '
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Standard Method: {0}", standardResults.Count()))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("LINQ Expressions: {0}", expressionResults.Count()))
Console.ReadLine()
```

What happens here is that the standard method correctly returns 1 result, while the LINQ Expressions method returns 0.  However, if the special value is added to the collection without using String.Format() (`myStrings.Add(stringToFind)`) then the expression returns the correct result as well.

Is there something that String.Format() does to change the encoding of the string, or anything that would effect how a constant expression is created for the string value?  Is there another way I could compare two values using LINQ expressions that would get me around this limitation?

Comment: Every string is the same. It does not magically get altered by String.Format().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB.NET equality operator does not do a reference comparison. Roughly speaking, it uses the `object.Equals` method (in contrast to `object.ReferenceEquals`). Expression trees use object reference equality.

Using `string.Format` does not do anything special. (There are no "special" strings).

Comment: Maybe not, but there obviously has to be some difference between String.Format(stringToFind) and stringToFind, otherwise both scenarios would produce the same result.  Are you saying that String.Format(stringToFind) generates a new instance of a string so that the ExpressionEquals evaluates to false?

Comment: @MikeC, yes exactly. The new instance of this particular string reference-compares as false.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use an overload to Expression.Call to specify using the Object.Equals method instead of Object.ReferenceEquals - Expression.Equal(left, right, False, GetType(Object).GetMethod("Equals", {GetType(Object), GetType(Object)})) and that did the trick!